# yii display the form and view in the same page

Tags: php, yii

This is my first time working with Yii Framework.

I have a model called apartment.

Is it possible to combine the edit form and display view of the apartment in one page?

Here is the code in the view controller

```
public $modelName = 'Apartment';
public function actionView($id = 0) {
            Yii::app()->bootstrap->plugins['tooltip'] = array(
                    'selector'=>' ', 
                    'options'=>array(
                            'placement'=>'top', 
                    ),  
            );  

            $this->render('view', array(
                    'model' =>  $this->loadModelWith(array('windowTo', 'objType', 'city')),
                    'statistics' => Apartment::getApartmentVisitCount($id),
            )); 
    }
```

Comment: short answer is yes. in your view file add something like $this->renderPartial( '_form', array( 'model' $yourmodel ) ) - _form being your edit subview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view file add something like -

`$this->renderPartial( '_form', array( 'data' => $yourmodel ) )`

_form being your edit subview.

Please post more of your code so stack overflow users can help with your specific problem.

look at this for more detail - 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail
and this - 
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/23012-understanding-render-and-renderpartial/

Comment: I have used your code as following 
$this->renderPartial('backend/_form', array('model'=>$model))
and it gives me Undefined variable: model as $model is not defined.
I tried to replace $model with $data which is the object used to display the fields of my model and the same exception appears.
any suggestion?

Comment: in that case you should do the opposite in your view file - `$this->renderPartial('backend/_form', array('data'=>$model))`